# Writing a bash file to run a python program for all folders in a directory

Tags: python, bash

I currently wrote a program to take the standard deviation of a single set of data. I have over 200 folders, each with their own set of data. I am attempting to write a bash file that will execute this program for all folders (while outputting all of the standard deviation into a master file as dictated in python).

So far I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

for D in SAND; do python sample.py
  [ -d "$D" -a -x "$D/all" ] && "$D/all"
done
```

Note: SAND is my directory.

But this does not work. Please help.

In addition, when I try other examples and run them I keep having the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sample.py", line 1, in <module>
    f=open("default")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'default'
```

even though I DO have the data file of "default" in the folders.

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind for a detailed walkthrough.

Comment: If you need to be *in* the directory before you run the Python script, well, you need your script to do that.

Comment: Is the `default` file inside the `all` directory, or inside the same directory that contains `all`?

Comment: How do I have to be in "all" of the directory? and the default file is in EVERY sub folder of SAND. I apologize for these questions. I am not familiar with bash.

Comment: Forget all. Pretend I have folder 1 and folder 2 in the giant folder SAND. I am unable to run the bash file due to the error no such file exists "default" even if I have "default" in all the folders.

Comment: Yes, because when you run `python sample.py SAND/foo/all`, it's looking for `default` in THE DIRECTORY YOU'RE IN RIGHT NOW, not in `SAND/foo`.

Frankly, the better solution would be to fix your Python script to look for `SAND/foo/default` when passed `SAND/foo/all`, if that's your data file convention.

Comment: ...however, you also have the option of changing directories into `SAND/foo` and then running the Python script from there. I already edited my answer to show you how to do this. What more do you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below assumes that `SAND` is the literal name of your directory.

First choice: Use a loop.

```sh
for d in SAND/*/all; do
  python sample.py "$d"
done
```

...or, if you need to change into the directory that's found...

```sh
orig_dir=$PWD
for d in SAND/*/all; do
  (cd "$d/.." && exec python "$orig_dir/sample.py" all)
done
```

---

Second choice: Use `find`.

I'd suggest searching directly for the targets named `all`:

```sh
find SAND -name all -exec python sample.py '{}' '+'
```

---

Alternately, with POSIX find, you can have `find` invoke a shell to perform more logic:

```sh
find SAND -type d -exec bash -c \
  'for d; do [[ -d "$d/all" ]] && python sample.py "$d/all"; done' _ '{}' +
```

---

If `SAND` is a variable name, not a literal directory, change `SAND` in the above to `"$SAND"`, with the quotes (and, ideally, make it lower-case -- by convention, only environment variables and shell builtin variables should be all-caps to avoid namespace conflicts).

Comment: I ran your first choice and it worked? However, I keep running into the problem Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sample.py", line 1, in <module>
    f=open("default")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'default'

even though I DO have the data file of "default" in the folders.

Comment: We're not a generalized troubleshooting service -- ideally, each StackOverflow "question" has exactly one well-isolated, clearly-asked, reproducible question, and that question gets one or more well-focused answers. Extending "questions" with extra questions is bad form -- additional questions should be asked separately.

Comment: Okay. I've added a second branch of the first example.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could skip bash altogether and modify your Python script. `os.walk()` allows you to visit each directory in turn:

```
import os,sys

for arg in sys.argv[1:] or ['.']:
  for dirpath, _, filenames in os.walk(arg):
    for filename in filenames:
      if filename == 'all':
        all_file = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
        default_file = os.path.join(dirpath, 'default')
        # ... whatever you do with SAND/foo/all
        # foo = open(all_file)
        # std_dev = bar(foo)
        # ... I'll just print them
        print all_file, default_file
```